Xquery, como mostrar el resultado con etiquetas XML y que se visualice correctamente
Para una actividad de clase estoy usando basex con 3 archivos XML. De momento llevo bastante bien las consultas, pero al obtener el resultado me sale todo en una linea corrida en vez de estar estructurado como en un XML.
dejo aqui mi consulta en xquery y el resultado que obtengo. Me gustaria obtener algo asi:
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>

Mi consulta es esta
let $actividad1 := (for $a in aeropuertos/aeropuerto
  where starts-with($a/pais,"A") or starts-with($a/pais,"E")
  order by $a/pais
  return <li>{$a/pais/data()}</li>)
  return <ul>{$actividad1}</ul>

y mi resultado es este
<ul><li>Afghanistan</li><li>Afghanistan</li><li>Afghanistan</li><li>Afghanistan</li><li>Albania</li><li>Albania</li><li>Albania</li><li>Albania</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Argentina</li><li>Armenia</li><li>Armenia</li><li>Armenia</li><li>Australia</li><li>Azerbaijan</li><li>Azerbaijan</li><li>Azerbaijan</li><li>Azerbaijan</li><li>Ecuador</li><li>Ecuador</li><li>Ecuador</li><li>Ecuador</li><li>Egypt</li><li>Egypt</li><li>Egypt</li><li>El Salvador</li><li>El Salvador</li><li>Estonia</li></ul>

Gracias de antemano

Añade
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method "xml";

declare option output:indent "yes";

al principio de tu código XQuery.
